# Why are empty folders with GUIDs for names being created in my AppData/Local/ folder?

Tags: windows-7, windows

What is causing this, and how do I stop it?  This is a standard, non-admin account.  I've run CCleaner and cleanmgr.exe and they're still there.  I can easily delete them but I want to know the source of the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Windows Live Essentials installed then at least some of these folders may be created each time Windows Live Setup performs its (twice-daily) version check.

Perhaps compare the timestamps on the folders with the log files created at the same time in `%localappdata%\Microsoft\WLSetup\Logs`.

Example of MSN Messenger (part of Live Essentials) accessing one of these folders:

[image: ProcMonOutput]

You can try monitoring the AppData\Local folder by using MS' [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) (as in the picture).  If they are being created at boot, then you can log them in ProcMon by enabling boot logging.

To configure Boot Logging, select "Enable Boot Logging" from the Options Menu, restart Windows and start Process Monitor again.

Info/Sources: [1](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/what-is-creating-the-hex-folders-hex-names-in/1560e13c-a259-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5) [2](http://www.w7forums.com/mysterious-folders-my-appdata-local-folder-t9388p12.html) [3](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7itprogeneral/thread/e73e686b-7e6f-45ed-a552-a83565435daf/)